# Declare new type Jboss Drools

Tags: jboss, field, drools, declare

i need declare a new type in my drl like this example.

```
package com.sample


import com.sample.DroolsTest.Message;

declare Variavel
    valor : Integer
end



rule "Hello World"
    when

        m : Message( status == Message.HELLO, myMessage : message )
```

----->   v : Variavel() Problem here, the variable is not instantiated

```
    then


        System.out.println( myMessage );
        m.setMessage( "Goodbye cruel world" );
        m.setStatus( Message.GOODBYE );
        update( m );
end

rule "GoodBye"
    when
        Message( status == Message.GOODBYE, myMessage : message )
    then
        System.out.println( myMessage );

end
```

My problem: I want use the variable without put this code

```
FactType personType = kbase.getFactType( "com.sample","Variavel" );
Object test = personType.newInstance();
                ksession.insert(test);
```

Its possible use the declared field without put this code when i fire the rule, like a static field?

Answer (score 3):

A type declaration in Drools is like declaring a class in Java. You have the type there, but no instances. What you can do is have a higher priority rule instantiate and insert it as a fact instead of having the application doing it. E.g.:

```java
declare Variavel
    valor : Integer
end

rule "create variable"
    salience 100
when
then
    insert( new Variavel() );
end

rule "Hello World"
when
    m : Message( status == Message.HELLO, myMessage : message )
    v : Variavel()
then
    // do something
end
```